# copy data from one google spreadsheet to another

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

i've made script for coping the details with the help of **id column** which will common in both sheets this code is not copying any detail 
[image: with the id i want to copy rest details in another sheet]

```
function myFunction()
{

}
function onOpen() {

  var subMenus = [
                   {name:"Generate farnchise username", functionName: "approveRequests"},
                 ];
    SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().addMenu("Custom Functions", subMenus);
}

function approveRequests() {
 var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
     sheet = ss.getActiveSheet(),
     sheetName = sheet.getName(),
     data = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
 if (sheetName == "g6-live-properties") {
  var range = sheet.getActiveRange(),
      startRow = range.getRowIndex(),
      numRows = range.getNumRows(),
      numCols = range.getNumColumns()
  if (numCols == 3) {
   if (data.length > 1) {
    var values = range.getValues(),
        nextSheet = ss.getSheetByName("11-Apr-60+"),
        lastRow = nextSheet.getLastRow();
    nextSheet.getRange(lastRow+1,1,numRows,3).setValues(values);
    sheet.deleteRows(startRow,numRows);
   } 
  } 
 } 
}
```

Comment: I assume the problem is that it isn't working. Is that correct? If so, where is it failing?

Comment: this code is doing cut-paste values from first sheet to second sheet..not copying data